# Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY

Tags: android, transactions

In the Login Screen in my app, I have put an ImageButton clicking on which is supposed to take to the screen 'FeedbackScreen'.
But when I click on it nothing happens. The logcat says:

"`Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY`".

This is the code I have put for my ImageButton:

```
imgBtnFeedback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, com.mycompany.myappname.fragment.FeedbackScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();            }
        });
```

I tried googling, but to no avail.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I am facing the same problem.
Have you managed to solve it?